# 2 dimensional grid component of Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid, grid, telerik

I need to use a two dimensional grid with headers in the left and the top on Silverlight.

Is it possible to configure a grid for that or I need to use an other control?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply using the `DataGrid` from Silverlight's own SDK?

Comment: The problem of the DataGrid is it can just support headers on one side of the grid and I would like in two sides like a matrix.

Comment: @user301089: `DataGrid` has row headers as well, you can change what is displayed in the row header by specifying your own Template for a `DataRowHeader` in the `DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle` property.